# Angular syntax of assigning outside directive's property?

Tags: angular

The following snippet is from [live example](https://stackblitz.com/angular/mjqablooqgy) of Angular official [tutorial](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives#binding-to-an-input-property):

```
<p appHighlight highlightColor="yellow">Highlighted in yellow</p>
<p appHighlight [highlightColor]="'orange'">Highlighted in orange</p>
```

Why the first `highlightColor` works without square brackets?

Comment: Because it's just a simple (string) value. Square brackets are only needed when you want to use dynamic expressions.

Comment: Thanks! I missed this part: https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#one-time-string-initialization